# Angular 6 *ngFor returns empty array while array it's actually full

Tags: firebase, angular6, ngfor

I'm currently developing a simple chat (like Facebook's) for a web application.
I'm using Angular 6 as framework and Firebase as my database.

When a user clicks on a certain conversation, I'm retrieving the previous messages using the `.on("child_added, //function here)` and then I'm pushing the results into an array which will be displayed using an `*ngFor` loop.

The weird issue I'm encountering is that the messages will be displayed sometimes correctly, and sometimes not displayed at all. When this happens, as soon as I click anywhere, the `*ngFor` will be called again and everything looks fine.

Using `console.logs` I found out that the data is pushed correctly into the array every time, but, for some reason, the `ngFor` (same with `ngAfterViewChecked`) sometimes will update and sometimes will just return an empty array.

**My .ts file (relevant parts):**

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  /*
    when everything works, this will be called everytime something changes
    (even after the array gets populated) 
    when the issue comes up, this will be called as usual but it won't be called after the array gets populated,
    thus returning an empty array the last time it was called 
  */

  console.log(this.msgService.messageList)
} 

//this will be called everytime a user clicks on a conversation on the left sidebar
getSpecConversation(conversation) {
  //emptying the array 
  this.msgService.messageList = [];

  //calling the .off using previous conversation key
  this.msgService.getConversation(this.msgService.selectedConversation.$key)
    .off('child_added');

  //getting messages of currently selected conversation
  this.msgService.getConversation(conversation.$key)
    .on('child_added', (data => {
      //push the data into array
      this.msgService.messageList.push(data.val());
    })
  );

  //storing currently selected conversation
  this.msgService.selectedConversation = conversation;
}
```

**the Template (relevant parts):**

```
<ul class="conversation-list">
  <li *ngFor="let message of msgService.messageList" class="conversation-item" [class.sender]="message.byUid == userInfoService.userUid">
    <p class="message">{{message.msg}}</p>
    <p class="msg-time">
    <span>{{message.time | date: 'shortTime'}}</span></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**The Service:**

```
getConversation(sid: string) {
  return this.database.ref('/messages')      
}
```

Thanks for the help

**Update**
If it helps, if I delete the `.off('child_added')` method, the problem won't show up anymore, but, when I send a new message, I would have the new message called multiple times in the view (not in database).

Answer (score 0):

Update your `template` and check that the array has data before you show it.

```
<ul class="conversation-list" *ngIf="msgService.messageList && msgService.messageList.length > 0">
  <li *ngFor="let message of msgService.messageList" class="conversation-item" [class.sender]="message.byUid == userInfoService.userUid">
    <p class="message">{{message.msg}}</p>
    <p class="msg-time">
    <span>{{message.time | date: 'shortTime'}}</span></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It could be a race condition - the `ngFor` loop could run before the array has any data in it, and then when you click around the page, a hook is running telling the `ngFor` to run again - this time finding data.

When you run the `ngIf` before it will check for data, as soon as it's available it allows the `ngFor` to run which will now have data to iterate over and display in your list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the template as suggested but the problem is still the same. I noticed that the error occur when I select a conversation, then select a different one and then select the first again. Though this is not always the case, seems to be the majority of the times. Thanks again

Comment: So, theoretically, you're answer seems to be correct. If I add a dummy `<p *ngIf="!msgService.messageList || msgService.messageList.length === 0">nothing here</p>` this will be visible for a very small time in between the change of conversations. When the problem occurs, the "nothing here" will be seen constantly. Once again, only when I do something, then it will show me the list of messages

Comment: That's strange - if you build your app in production `ng b --prod` and run does it work? Is there a bug with a lifecycle hook not firing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the data from a service, so it could be that you need to use the async pipe.

```
<li *ngFor="let message of msgService.messageList | async">
    <p class="message">{{message.msg}}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Message list isn't an observable / promise it is a static array so this won't work.

Comment: @sketchthat Ah yes you're right. I always used something like this to prevent this type of error. `*ngIf="msgService.messageList?.length > 0 && !isLoading"`  while `isLoading` would change depending on the status.

Comment: @ams Thanks for your answer. as sketchthat correctly said, messageList is a static array. Anyway, I tried something similar to what you said in the comment above, with a `isLoading` that will control a progress spinner. When user clicks on conversation,  `isLoading` will become true, thus showing only the spinner. Just underneath the part of code where I'm pushing the results to the array, I'm setting `isLoading` to false to hide the spinner and show the results. Same behavior, would work perfectly sometimes and do issue some others.